# I/O File Exception With Different Methods

Tags: java, file-io, ioexception

I am trying to calculate the weighted average of the array list from an input file. I made a file called "data.txt" with numbers of "0.5 3 70 80 90 20." I'm having issues with reading the input file and and showing it in the output file. I know my method names are right but I concerned my first method and last method. **I just what my output file to show: “The weighted average of the numbers is 42.5, when using the data 10.0, 70.0, 90.0, 80.0, 20.0,
 where 0.5 is the weight used, and the average is computed after dropping the lowest 3 values.”** I'm a beginner with I/O exceptions.

Here is my code:

```
public class Total {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

       ArrayList<Double> inputValues = getData();
       double weightedAvg = calcWeightedAvg(inputValues);
       printResults(inputValues, weightedAvg);

    }

    public static ArrayList<Double> getData() throws FileNotFoundException {       

        // Prompts for the input and output file names
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);           
        String inputFileName = "data.txt";
        ArrayList<Double> inputValues = new ArrayList<Double>();                        

        File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
        in.close();


        return inputValues;
    }

    public static double calcWeightedAvg(ArrayList<Double> inputValues) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // calc weighted av           
           double weight = 0.0;
           double sum = 0;
           double average = 0;                
           int i = 0;
           double weightavg = 0;
           int lowNum = 0;

            // Calcuates the average of the array list with the lowest numbers dropped        
            for (i = 0; i < inputValues.size(); i++) 
            {
                if (inputValues.get(i) > lowNum) 
                {
                   sum = sum + inputValues.get(i);
                }
            }
            average = sum / inputValues.size();

            weightavg = average * weight;
            weightavg = weightavg + 10;        

            return weightavg;
    }

    public static void printResults(ArrayList<Double> inputValues, double weightedAvg) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Output File: ");
        String outputFileName = scnr.next();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);
            System.out.print("The weighted average of the numbers is " + weightedAvg + ", when using the data " + inputValues);
            out.close();
        }
}
```

when I run my program it shows:

```
Output File: new.txt
The weighted average of the numbers is NaN, when using the data []
```

Comment: If this is the complete code sample, then it looks like you never set any values to `inputValues`

Answer (score 0):

In your getData() method you are creating the inputValues ArrayList but did not add any values in to it, so the ArrayList is empty.

So after reading from data.txt add the values to the ArrayList and try.

Answer (score 0):

```
        //read to string
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("data.txt"))));
    String line = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }

    //split string line to string numbers
    String[] numbers = sb.toString().trim().split(" ");
    List<Double> listDoubles = new ArrayList<Double>();

    // parse string numbers to Doubles
    for (String strNumber : numbers){
        listDoubles.add(Double.valueOf(strNumber));
    }

    //do your business logic with doubles in listDoubles        
    //write to file
    //close streams
```

I suggest to use .csv format for such input data